# To simplify an expression further

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have solved the following Eq to get hz:

```
sol = Solve[(-(-1 + b) (hz^3 + hz^3 Log[hz^4/lamda^4]) + 
     2/3 b hz^3 Log[((Fπ)^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)]) == 0, hz]
```

I wanted to check if  one the solutions like sol[[4, 1, 2]] satisfies the Eq:

```
FullSimplify[(-(-1 + b) (hz^3 + hz^3 Log[hz^4/lamda^4]) + 
    2/3 b hz^3 Log[((Fπ)^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)]) /. 
  hz -> sol[[4, 1, 2]], 
 lamda > 0 && alpha[3] > 0 && Fπ > 0 && b ∈ Reals]
```

I got the following answer:

```
1/3 (E^(-1 + (2 b Log[(Fπ^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)])/(
   3 (-1 + b))))^(3/4) lamda^3 (-3 (-1 + b) (1 + 
      Log[E^(-1 + (2 b Log[(Fπ^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)])/(
        3 (-1 + b)))]) + 2 b Log[(Fπ^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)])
```

It should be zero but Mathematica can not simplify it further. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `F[Pi]` a variable in itself or `F * Pi`?

Comment: @JasonB, it appears `Fπ` is indeed the name of a variable and not the product of `F` and `π`. Your first edit was correct. At least that's how it looks from the code and the expected result.

Comment: okay - I was afraid I messed it up, you never really see Pi as part of a name

Comment: I still have something wrong, when I enter OP's first two commands, it tells me that `sol[[4,2,1]]` doesn't exist, it finds a single solution

Answer (score 3):

I see, you have stated, that all variables are real (some are also positive, but still real). Therefore, `ComplexExpand[expr]` is equivalent to your expression.

```
1/3 (E^(-1 + (2 b Log[(Fπ^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)])/(
   3 (-1 + b))))^(
 3/4) lamda^3 (-3 (-1 + b) (1 + 
      Log[E^(-1 + (2 b Log[(Fπ^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)])/(
        3 (-1 + b)))]) + 2 b Log[(Fπ^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)]);

ComplexExpand[%]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: ComplexExpand[expr] works and results in 0 in version 9.0.0.0, but in version 10.0.1.0, it doesn't yield zero.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Jason B](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b) in a Comment, I noticed that

```
eq1 = (-(-1 + b) (hz^3 + hz^3 Log[hz^4/lamda^4]) + 
        2/3 b hz^3 Log[((Fπ)^4 alpha[3]^2)/(16 lamda^6)])
sol = Solve[eq1 == 0, hz]
```

yields only one solution,

```
(* {{hz -> E^((3 - 3 b - 8 b Log[2] + 8 b Log[Fπ] - 12 Log[lamda] + 
            4 b Log[alpha[3]])/(12 (-1 + b)))}} *)
```

Hence, `sol[[4, 1, 2]]` does not exist.  (Perhaps, the OP used an older version of *Mathematica*.  I have "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)".)  With the result above,

```
eq2 = eq1 /. sol[[1, 1]];
FullSimplify[eq2, lamda > 0 && alpha[3] > 0 && Fπ > 0 && b ∈ Reals]
```

runs at least 30 minutes without returning an answer.  Further,

```
ComplexExpand[eq2]
```

provides no simplification.  Instead, I used

```
cf[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Log, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e];
FullSimplify[eq2, lamda > 0 && alpha[3] > 0 && Fπ > 0 && b ∈ Reals, 
    ComplexityFunction -> cf];
FullSimplify[% /. z1_ Log[z2_] :> Log[PowerExpand[z2^z1]], 
    lamda > 0 && alpha[3] > 0 && Fπ > 0 && b ∈ Reals]
(* 0 *)
```

Evidently, `FullSimplify` has difficulty simplifying sums of `Log` with complicated arguments.